# Using $(window).width in Selenium

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, window, selenium-webdriver

I have a website using  `$(window).width()` in a JS function.

In Selenium I want to test if the function was executed and a div has the value of `$(window).width() * 0.8`.

Is there a possibility to do this? Setting the browser width to some value doesn't work. Probably because there still is the window border which is included in the one calculation but not in the other.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a JavascriptExecutor:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.documentElement.clientWidth");
```

That will return the width of the viewport, if you want the height try:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.documentElement.clientHeight")
```